# Python - with open() except (FileNotFoundError)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems strange to me that

```
with open(file, 'r')
```

can report

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]
```

but I can't catch that in some way and continue on.  Am I missing something here or is it really expected that you use isfile() or similar before a with open() ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to handle exception

```
 try:
     with open( "a.txt" ) as f :
         print(f.readlines())
 except Exception:
     print('not found')
     #continue if file not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will catch any exception, not just File Not Found, and will disguise any program bugs that you may be unaware of. You can instead catch `FileNotFoundError` or `IOError`, depending on your version of Python.

Answer (score -3):

If you're getting a FileNotFound error, the problem is most likely that the file name or the path to the file is incorrect. If you're trying to read AND write to a file that doesn't exist yet, change the mode from `'r'` to `'w+'`. It may also help to write out the full path before the file, for Unix users as:

```
'/Users/paths/file'
```

Or better yet, us os.path so that your path can be run on other operating systems.

```
import os
with open(os.path.join('/', 'Users', 'paths', 'file'), 'w+)
```